# passing arguments to python binary executable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run a python script passing arguments in the command line. The way I am doing is the following:

```
from sys import argv
x, y = argv
```

When I try to run the script:

```
./tst.py 23 1421 (the integers being the arguments)
```

I get encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am ultimately converting this script as a binary using pyinstaller and the executable would be called from any external application (for eg: Java code).

Any help would be much appreciated on this particular issue and any better method of passing argument to the binary ultimately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` includes the script name, so you have **three** values in the list, not two.

Take that into account when unpacking; either ignore the first element:

```
x, v = sys.argv[1:]
```

or include another target:

```
script, x, v = sys.argv
```

From the [`sys.argv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).